# Delete duplicate Item in ObservableCollection ? In Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#

How can delete duplicate items in `ObservableCollection<Customer>`
Class `Customer` has a `string Name`, s`tring PhoneNumber`

If I add `Name = Jonh`, in first time - OK

In second `Name = Jonh` (duplicate) <-------------------- 
I want the duplicate item to be removed.

(Delete duplicate Name, not delete PhoneNumber)

Answer (score 7):

One way you can implement this is to make sure the name is not already in the collection before adding it to the collection.  In WP7, this can be achieved with a simple LINQ statement.  You can do something like this, assuming your collection is called "cusomterList"

```
public bool AddCustomer(Customer customer) {
  if(null != customer) {
    if(customerList.Count(c => c.Name == customer.Name) == 0) {
      customer.Add(customer);
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Don't use the `Count()`. It performs a O(n) iteration, where as `Any()` only checks until first occurrence. Like this: `if (customerList.Any(x => x.Name == customer.Name)) { ... }`

Answer (score 5):

Using LINQ to find duplicate item each time has complicity O(N). And inserting all items is O(N^2) at worst.

You can use Dictionary (based on hash table) instead (average inserting time is O(N) ).

I create collection inherited from `ObservableCollection` that provides unique elements:

```
  public class Customer
  {
    public string Name { get; set;}

    public override int  GetHashCode()
    {
        return Name.GetHashCode();
    }

    public override bool  Equals(object obj)
    {
      if(obj == null || !(obj is Customer))
        return false;

        return (obj as Customer).Name.Equals(Name);
    }
  }
  public class UniqueObservableCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
  {
    private Dictionary<T, bool> _itemsDict = new Dictionary<T, bool>();

    protected override void  InsertItem(int index, T item)
    {
      if(_itemsDict.ContainsKey(item))
        return;
      _itemsDict.Add(item, true);
        base.InsertItem(index, item);
    }

    protected override void  ClearItems()
    {
      _itemsDict.Clear();
        base.ClearItems();
    }

    protected override void  RemoveItem(int index)
    {
      if(index >= base.Items.Count) 
        return;
      var item = base.Items[index];
      if(!_itemsDict.ContainsKey(item))
        return;
      _itemsDict.Remove(item);
        base.RemoveItem(index);
    }
  }
```

You need to override GetHashCode and Equals methods in your Customer class.

Comment: Use [IEquatable<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187.aspx) instead of `GetHashCode()`. It's much better practice, and cleaner code. Plus, you avoid hash-collisions.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, if you want your `Customer` class to be compared on the name, then you should implement `IEquatable<Customer>` on your class, like this:

```
public bool Equals(Customer other)
{
    if (other == null)
        return false;

    return this.Name == other.Name;
}
```

Secondly, once you insert a item into your `ObservableCollection<Customer>` you either need to do a check, like this:

```
if (customers.Contains(newCustomer) == false)
    customers.Add(newCustomer)
```

Or implement a custom implementation of the `ObservableCollection<T>` as Ivan suggested. Where you do the same check in.

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent adding duplicate entry using this code

```
if(collection.Any(p => p.Name == newPerson.Name) == false) 
{
     collection.Add(newPerson); 
}
else
{
//Show Message "Already Exist!"
}
```

This Works fine. Hope useful for you.